# Calculate working days and working time in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to calculate working time, excluding weekends and holidays.

This formula works in Excel:

```
=(NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2,S$2:S$12)-1)*(10/24)+
IF(NETWORKDAYS(C2,C2,S$2:S$12),MEDIAN(MOD(C2,1),"18:00","08:00"),"18:00")
-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(B2,B2,S$2:S$12)*MOD(B2,1),"18:00","08:00")
```

This is what I have in PowerBI so far:

```
Time = 
(
NETWORKDAYS('Data'[CreatedTime],'Data'[CommentTime],1,Holidays)-1)*(10/24)
+
IF(NETWORKDAYS('Data'[CommentTime],'Data'[CommentTime],1,Holidays),
MEDIAN(MOD('Data'[CommentTime],1),"18:00","08:00"),"18:00")
-
MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS('Data'[CreatedTime],'Data'[CreatedTime],1,Holidays)
*
MOD('Data'[CreatedTime],1),"18:00","08:00"
)
```

The CreatedTime and CommentTime are as follows:

[image: CreatedCommentTime]

The only time that should be counted is between 08:00am and 18:00pm on a weekday and not including any holidays.

The holidays table contains a list of dates to be exlcuded.

So for the example above, the 1st and 2nd of January should be excluded (1st was a Sunday, 2nd was in the holidays table). Meaning the time elapsed should be counted from 03/01/2023 08:00 - 18:00 and 04/01/2023 08:00 - 17:40.

So the total hours should be 19hrs 40mins.  I can calculate this in Excel however the MOD and MEDIAN functions are not the same in PowerBI.

The error in PowerBI is:

> Too many arguments were passed to the MEDIAN function. The maximum
> argument count for the function is 1.

Is there any way to update my formula in PowerBI to work?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: MEDIAN() and MOD() won't work here and you're passing them strings which will also fail. You need to split your formula into 3: NETWORKDAYS() for whole days and then an individual time calculations for the first and last day. The formula is quite long but should just be a case of working through the logic.